# Magento 2: Invalid block type: Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, compile

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class EmergentMagento\Emergent\Model\Payment\Interceptor does not exist
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:91]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:247]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php:57]
#15 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#16 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#17 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#19 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#21 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#22 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#24 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:162]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#29 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#31 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]</pre>Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class EmergentMagento\Emergent\Model\Payment\Interceptor does not exist<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/Factory.php:40]
#5 Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Factory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php:116]
#6 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data->getMethodInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/klarna/module-kp/Plugin/Payment/Helper/DataPlugin.php:242]
#9 Klarna\Kp\Plugin\Payment\Helper\DataPlugin->aroundGetMethodInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#10 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#11 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Payment/Helper/Data/Interceptor.php:26]
#12 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor->getMethodInstance() called at [vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/CcGenericConfigProvider.php:43]
#13 Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#16 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:203]
#17 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:179]
#18 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:273]
#19 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:236]
#20 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#21 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#22 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#23 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:167]
#24 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:273]
#25 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:236]
#26 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#27 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#28 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#29 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:46]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:91]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:247]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php:57]
#46 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#47 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#48 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#49 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#50 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#51 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#52 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#53 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#54 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#55 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:162]
#56 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#57 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#58 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#59 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#60 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#61 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#62 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#63 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#64 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#65 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#66 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#67 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#68 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]</pre>
```

I have this issue after install the extension EmergentMagento\Emergent. When I turn on developer mode, it show this bug. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by changed

\EmergentMagento\Emergent\sdk\Emergent $emergent

to

\EmergentMagento\Emergent\Sdk\Emergent $emergent

in file app/code/EmergentMagento/Emergent/Model/Payment.php